# Are tautologies in compile-time evaluated code guaranteed to be executed / optimized away?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++20, c++-concepts

Is the compiler guaranteed to evaluate boolean `constexpr` expressions that are `"tautologies"` (e.g. always `true` or `false` respectively) in a `constexpr` environment?

#### Minimal Example / Clarification

For example, in the following code snipplet (at the line marked with `(1)`) I invoke a function in a `constexpr` environment, which I intend to cause a compile time error whenever a `non-constexpr` function is passed. At least the compiler I use (`g++-10.0`) does this, even though it could also realize that the expression is always `true` without evaluating it. The reason I ask this question, is because -- to the best of my knowledge -- in a non-constepxr context, an expression like `i >= std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` is optimized away to `true` for an `int i` .

```cpp
#include <limits>
constexpr int example_function() { return 1;}
constexpr bool compileTimeErrorDesired = example_function() || true; // (1)
```

#### Application Example

If the behavior in `(1)`  is guaranteed, it can for instance be used in a `concept`, in order to execute different code, depending on whether a function provided as template argument can be evaluated at compile time. I implemented a very short (`7 lines-of-code`) example which does exactly that [here at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dnuq_R).

#### Question

Is the line (1) guaranteed to cause a compile time error if called with a non-constexpr function?

**edit** Inserted clarification, simplify example due to feedback.

Comment: You mean when `example_function` is not constexpr?  `example_function() || true` is not a constant expression if `example_function` is not constexpr, and compilers are required to diagnose non-constant expression to `static_assert`.

Comment: What do you mean by "with a more obvious tautology, no compile time error is thrown"? If `example_function` is not declared `constexpr`, then g++ does correctly reject `static_assert(example_function() || true)`.

Comment: @L.F. yes, if example_function is not constexpr, the code above is supposed to fail, which it does not when I assert  `example_function() || true ` even though it is not a constant expression. So the fact that gcc does not fail while trying to evaluate the assertion in that case is a compiler bug?

Comment: @L.F. I rechecked that with the compiler at compilerexplorer, and I think this was due to a compiler error at my machine: At compilerExplroer's version of gcc-trunk, a compile time error is thrown in the line with the static assertion, just as I wanted it to. I will update my question in order to reflect that, sorry.

Comment: @aschepler You are right. When I wrote the question I did not receive a compile time error with my compiler at my local machine, I rechecked on compiler_explorer and it also throws a compile time error for "example_function() || true" which was intended. My question is: is this behavior guaranteed?

Comment: Is what behavior guaranteed? I don't understand, at all, what the question is asking.

Comment: It's guaranteed. `example_function() || true` is not a *constant expression* according to C++ rules, even if its value is mathematically constant.

Comment: IMO problem in fact refers to "AS IF rule" which is nicely [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718279/1387438). Also [order of evaluating operator arguments](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/eval_order.html) has impact on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's guaranteed that `f() || true` is not a core constant expression if `f` is not a constexpr function: (constant expressions are more restrictive than core constant expressions) [[expr.const]/2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.2)

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the
>   evaluation of `e`, **following the rules of the abstract machine**,
>   would **evaluate** one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a
>     trivial destructor ([class.dtor]) [ *Note:* Overload resolution
>     is applied as usual  — *end note* ];
> - [...]

It's also guaranteed that the program is ill-formed (diagnostic required) if non-constant expressions are used in contexts that require constant expressions.  Note that `||` is defined to evaluate from left to right: [[expr.log.or]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.log.or#1)

> The `||` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to `bool`. It returns `true` if either of its
>   operands is `true`, and `false` otherwise. Unlike `|`, `||` guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not
>   evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.

In other words, `true || f()` is a core constant expression because `f()` is not evaluated, whereas `f() || true` is not because `f()` is evaluated.

Whether or not an expression is a constant expression has nothing to do with optimization — constant expressions are defined based on the rules of the abstract machine.

Comment: Though if it must be a CTCE, as the compiler has to evaluate it in order to prove that, it already has the value. And I don't know any which pessimizes by throwing that away, despite as-if allowing so.

Comment: @Deduplicator May I ask ... what does CTCE stand for?

Comment: compile-time constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

The terms "executed" isn't exactly appropriate when it comes to constant expressions. Even "evaluated" might be used with care, because whether an expression is a constant expression depends partly on behavior of what would happen if the expression were evaluated, but is not considered an evaluation in the most strict sense.

[[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const) describes requirements for a number of different contexts of "compile-time behavior", including "constant expression". [expr.const]/(5.2) says that if evaluating an expression would evaluate a non-constexpr function, the expression is not a core constant expression, and therefore not a constant expression. If the expression is used in a context requiring a constant expression (like `static_assert`, a non-type template argument, etc.), the program is ill-formed and there must be a diagnostic message. There is no rule permitting anything like allowing a non-constant expression in such a context or skipping some parts of the hypothetical evaluation if the expression is a converted constant expression and the result value of the expression can be determined despite not being a constant expression.

So if `example_function` is not declared `constexpr`, then `example_function() || true` is not a constant expression because the evaluation would require calling the function. But `true || example_function()` is a constant expression, since the evaluation would not call the function.

Your `is_constexpr<T>` is guaranteed to work, because any semantic constraint violation involving a template parameter inside a *requires-expression* does not make the program ill-formed, but just makes the *requires-expression* result value `false` ([[expr.prim.req]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.req#6)). In `is_constexpr<example_function>`, using the non-constant expression `T()` as a template argument to `std::enable_if` via the default template argument instantiated by `ConstexprHelper<T>` is such a semantic error, so the *requires-expression* has value `false`.